# how make python program run hidden mode in .exe format?

Tags: python, py2exe

I have a python program that run without console in app.pyw file format. I converted that program to .exe file using py2exe using this script

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['app.pyw'])
```

now the app.exe application working fine,but app will not work without console window. I want to run my app without console window in .exe format

Answer (score 1):

(I cant add a comment ) 
I suggest that you read the module 'distutils.core' where setup is defined.
The para 'console=['app.pyw']' might be  your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here you don't need to add .pyw just edit your py2exe setup script

replace console=

by windows=

should be something like that:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=["app.pyw"])
```

Comment: But i could have been more specific Ty mou

Answer (score 0):

try setup(windows=["name"]) instead of console. When theres no GUI window to run maybe itl hide it..